# Sencha Touch Scrollable Panel Background Color

Tags: css, background, extjs, scrollable

I have a panel in Sencha Touch defined as so:

```
    var albumContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        id: 'album_container',
        html: '',
        flex: 1,
        scrollable: 'vertical',
        padding: 0,
    });
```

Everything works, however since adding the scrollable property the panel has had a white background, which I'm trying to get rid off, however just setting the background of #album_container, even as !important, does nothing. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Damir H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I had to change the background color of the items.

```
items: [{
    style: 'background-color:#F00',
    layout: 'hbox', padding: '5',
    // some other stuff
```